# Add Class to body tag

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I am trying to add a class of "single" to my body tag if the page I am on, matches a documenttype alias from umbraco.

i have tried this:

```
<body @{global.CurrentPage.DocumentTypeAlias == "blogItem" ? "class='single'" : '';}>
```

It should add the class "single" if the currentpage i am on, has a DocumentTypeAlias of "blogItem".

I can't get this to work, and i haven't been able to find a solution so far. 
What am i doing wrong here ?

it gives me the error:
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between "string" and "char"

**Edit**
Changing it to this,

```
<body class="@{global.CurrentPage.DocumentTypeAlias == "blogItem" ? "single" : "";}">
```

just gives a new error...
Only assignment, call, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: in C# `''` is a char. You need a string `""`.

Comment: that gives me a new error. and changing it to the new "edit", does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of things wrong with your syntax. As already pointed out your `''` quotes are wrong, but you also need to surround your expression with `()` rather than `{}`:

```
<body @(global.CurrentPage.DocumentTypeAlias == "blogItem" ? "class='single'" : "")>
```

Comment: That was exactly it ! but what changes when using () instead of {} ?